# http response 304 slow

Tags: html, performance, web, loading

I notice if i refresh my web page 2-5 seconds after it loaded the load is very slow. if i wait more then 5 sec its fast again. so i inspected the request with fiddler and find out that the css + js file are slow on the second load , it doesn't matter if the files are cached or not.
I can't figure   out why.
I attached fiddler timeline for both cases.
I'll appreciate any ideas you'll have.
Thanks!

[fiddler screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phMwB.jpg)

Comment: What webserver is serving these files?

Comment: HI, IIS ver 8.0 on a win 2012 VM hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try some basic troubleshooting like: clear cache, open it on a private window...